# C. Method not reading correctly from textfile when figure contains 2 integers

Tags: c

I have a basic math program where I store the results in a textfile. Each result is stored on a new line in the textfile, and the figures varies between 0 and 15.

The textfile can looking something like this;

```
1
0
4
9
12
etc.
```

with each figure on a new line (dont know why the numbers are on the same line here).

The program should find the highest result. It does not matter if there is more than one figure with the same value.

My problem is that, when the figure contains two integers my method only takes the last one and stores this. If I have 15 for example, 5 is stored.

My method looks like this. Would be greatfull for some help!

```
void BestResult(){

    char c;
    int max=0;
    int converted=0;

    if (access("ResultScore.txt", F_OK) != -1){
        fPointerScore=fopen("ResultScore.txt", "rt");
        while((c=fgetc(fPointerScore))!=EOF){
        converted=atoi(&c);
        if (converted>max){
            max=converted;
        }
        }
        printf("\nThe best result is : %d/15 at the moment", max);

    }

    AskUserWhatToDo();

}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior for passing a non nullterminated string to a library function expecting a correct string.

Comment: How can this be fixed? The method works fine if there is only one integer...

Comment: No, it is not fine, even with a single digit. The code exhibits undefined behavior in all cases where `c` is not set to `'\0'`.

Comment: Do yo have any suggestions on how this method shoud look?

Comment: `scanf("%d", &converted);`

Comment: Does code need to handle numbers like `-123` and `+456`?

Comment: No, only numbers betwen +1 and +15

Answer (score 0):

You are storing it in a character. So char will store only '5' and not '15'. Use data type string or char*.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is, it read all characters(in your file one by one)

Your code need needs to detect end of the line

```
ch!= '\n'
```

Try this:

```
 char buffer[10]; /* as big as the biggest number */
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    double d, dMax = 1000, dMin = -1000;

    while ((ch= getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (ch!= '\n')
            buffer[i++] = ch;
        else {
            buffer[i] = '\0';
            d = atof(buffer);
            if (d > dMax) dMax = d;
            if (d < dMin) dMin = d;
            i = 0;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Suggest `char ch;` --> `int ch;` for portable `while ((ch= getc(fp)) != EOF) {` operation.

Comment: Initial values of `dMax = 1000, dMin = -1000` seem strange.  Suggest reviewing code.

Comment: Good points.My intention was to make code as simple as possible. otherwise, I usually use dmax=INFINITY and dmin=-INFINITY

Comment: I doubt code usually uses `dmax=INFINITY` and `dmin=-INFINITY`.  More likely `dmax=-INFINITY` and `dmin=+INFINITY`, else the compares are pointless: `d > dMax` will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'll solve the problem in this way

```
int BestResult(FILE *infile) {
    char buf[100];
    int len=0;
    int i=0;

    while(fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),infile)!=NULL)
        len++;

    rewind(infile);

    int *numbers;
    numbers = (int *) malloc (len * sizeof(int));

    while(fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),infile)!=NULL)
        sscanf(buf,"%i",&numbers[i]);

    int maxnum=numbers[0];

    for(i=1;i<len;i++)
        if(numbers[i]>maxnum)
            maxnum=numbers[i];

    return maxnum;

}
```

So first read the size of the file that defines the number of elements in your case, then allocate an array of integers to the number of items you find, fill the array by parsing line by line with the `fgets` and fill the array with `sscanf`, then research the maxnumber.